# Associate external libraries with Non Executable Jar

Tags: java, jar

I have created class file which has dependencies to other external jars. I have generated a non executable jar for my program and I am using class loader to access methods in my jar file.  But my call is failing with NoClassfoundException on dependent jars. Dependent jars are placed in the same location as my jar file that I am trying to load using classloader.

a. Is there anything more I need to do to associated the external jar files.
b. Is there any other option get this done without having to convert my jar file to executable jar.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following pom.xml I actually used it to make a single executable jar but I modified it now for non-executable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ga</groupId>
<artifactId>GAChainMR</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
......
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Skip the tests run. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Sources generation -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
             </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I build the jar using mvn package command and found all the dependencies in a jar, try and let me know.
Add depencies for the external jars in the above pom

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and let you know if it worked

Comment: Thank you. With the approach you provided, I was able to proceed further for now. But I was hoping to find a solution that would help me keep the dependent libraries independent of the jar that I am building and not build into a single jar file? Do you if that is possible